# Why is Subversion giving me this error message?

Tags: svn

I am getting the following error while commiting data into Subversion:

```
svn: Can't create directory '/usr/share/repos/db/transactions/'
```

I have tried both command line and the eclipse-plugin options. Both give the above results.

Comment: Post the command you're using. Something is misconfigured on your server.

Comment: svn commit somefile.txt -m "Some Text"

Comment: The OS/Distribution of the SVN repository is stored as well as the method of communication with the repository (apache, svnserve, etc.) would help greatly in tracking down this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix the permissions for the repository (on the server side). The directory should have rwx set for the user and/or group under which the Subversion-server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using svn+apache ? If so, the user the httpd process is running as must have write access to  all parent directories in the repository path.

If doing it with a local repository do you have write access to that directory?

Answer (score 0):

A few assumptions:

- Your running some form of *nix
  because you are getting what looks
  like a permission problem.
- You are
  using subversion through apache.

More then likely when the repository was created it was done as root and now the apache user is trying to write to it.

```
sudo chown -R apache_user:apache_user /usr/share/repos
```

should do the trick for most distributions.

Of course you need to find out what user apache runs under your distribution for this to work.

Post some info on the OS/Distribution where the SVN repository is stored and how your are communicating with SVN and I can help more.